# radio button request syntax in view

Tags: html, django, button, radio-button

I'm trying to write an html form, that includes a radio button and keyword search. The code is here :

http://dpaste.com/115844/

The django view is not recognizing this syntax :

```
pubtypeid = request.GET['pubtypeid']
```

Can someone please help me to write this correctly ?

Thanks,

Ana

Answer (score 0):

You're using the "if" incorrectly. It should have two "=", not one.